# SQL : How can I get count from multiple tables into one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, one for website connection errors, one for successful website connections and another with name/location of each specific website.

- Table 1 has WebsiteClass_ID, Website_ID and Error_Date
- Table 2 has WebsiteClass_ID, Website_ID and Success_Date
- Table 3 has WebsiteClass_ID, Website Name and Location

I need to return the rate of error by WebsiteClass_ID by Website_ID per day. To do this, I need the count of errors per WebsiteClass_ID, Website_ID and Date from Table 1 and the count of successful connections per WebsiteClass_ID, Website_ID and Date from Table 2. I still need to return Website Name and Location from table 3 as well. The date field is different in Table 1 than it is in Table 2.

I can easily get the count for each in two different queries but would prefer to accomplish this in one query to avoid extra work in Excel. I created the two individual queries below but do not know how to merge them.

```
#QUERY
#TITLE-WEBSEROR
#SUBJECT-WEBSITE ERRORS PER DAY BY CLASS AND ID

SELECT

 A.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID          AS WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
,A.WEBSITE_ID                AS WEBSITE_ID
,A.ERROR_DATE                AS DATE_OF_ERROR
,COUNT(A.EVENT_NAME)         AS NUMBER_OF_ERRORS
,B.NAME                      AS WEBSITE_NAME
,B.LOCATION                  AS COMPANY_LOCATION

FROM

 &DATABASE..ERRORS      A
,&DATABASE..DETAILS     B

WHERE

   A.WEBSITE_ID = B.WEBSITE_ID

GROUP BY A.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, A.WEBSITE_ID, A.ERROR_DATE, B.NAME, B.LOCATION


#QUERY
#TITLE-WEBSCNFM
#SUBJECT-SUCCESSUL CONNECTIONS PER DAY BY CLASS AND ID

SELECT

 C.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID          AS WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
,C.WEBSITE_ID                AS WEBSITE_ID
,DATE(C.SUCCESS_DATE)        AS SUCCESSFUL_CONNECTION
,COUNT(C.SUCCESS)            AS COUNT_SUCCESS_CNCTN
,B.NAME                      AS WEBSITE_NAME
,B.LOCATION                  AS COMPANY_LOCATION

FROM

 &DATABASE..SUCCESS    C
,&DATABASE..DETAILS    B

WHERE

    C.WEBSITE_ID = B.WEBSITE_ID

GROUP BY C.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, C.WEBSITE_ID, DATE(C.SUCCESS_DATE), B.NAME, B.LOCATION
```

Data Sample:
[Table 1: Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxSQe.png)

[Table 2: Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkgDR.png)

[Table 3: Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8zOb.png)

Expected Results :

| Website_Class_ID | Website_ID | Date of Error or Success | Count of Errors | Count of Success | Website Name | Website Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ClassB | ID 2 | 12/1/2019 | 3 | 5 | Website #1 | USA |
| ClassC | ID 3 | 12/2/2019 | 1 | 6 | Website #2 | Canada |

```
SELECT
 `Errors$`.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
,`Errors$`.WEBSITE_ID
,`Errors$`.ERROR_DATE
,COUNT(`Errors$`.EVENT_NAME)
,`Details$`.NAME
,`Details$`.LOCATION
FROM
 `D:\mike\SnapCommerce Case Study\Data.xlsx`.`Errors$` `Errors$`,
 INNER JOIN `D:\mike\SnapCommerce Case Study\Data.xlsx`.`Details$` 
`Details$`
ON `Details$`.WEBSITE_ID = `Errors$`.WEBSITE_ID

GROUP BY `Errors$`.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, `Errors$`.WEBSITE_ID, 
`Errors$`.ERROR_DATE, `Details$`.NAME, `Details$`.LOCATION

UNION

SELECT
 `Success$`.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
,`Success$`.WEBSITE_ID
,DATE(`Success$`.SUCCESS_DATE)
,COUNT(`Success$`.SUCCESS)
,`Details$`.NAME
,`Details$`.LOCATION

FROM
 `D:\mike\SnapCommerce Case Study\Data.xlsx`.`Success$` `Success$`,
 INNER JOIN `D:\mike\SnapCommerce Case Study\Data.xlsx`.`Details$` 
`Details$`
ON `Details$`.WEBSITE_ID = `Success$`.WEBSITE_ID

GROUP BY `Success$`.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, `Success$`.WEBSITE_ID, 
`Success$`.SUCCESS_DATE, `Details$`.NAME, `Details$`.LOCATION
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help

Comment: please show us the result you expect, vertical joining or horizonqatlly

Comment: I added sample data and 2 rows of expected results. I had to mask some of the data so hopefully this helps. Essentially need to be able to see the counts of errors in one column which you can sort by class, website ID or date and the counts of success in another column which apply to the same class, website ID or date.

Comment: please share the scripts instead of image. it will help to create objects, data and solutions  fast.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically, You can use UNION, this would eliminate doubles as well.

If you need them use UNION ALL

```
SELECT
     A.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID          AS WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
    ,A.WEBSITE_ID                AS WEBSITE_ID
    ,A.ERROR_DATE                AS DATE_OF_ERROR
    ,COUNT(A.EVENT_NAME)         AS NUMBER_OF_ERRORS
    ,B.NAME                      AS WEBSITE_NAME
    ,B.LOCATION                  AS COMPANY_LOCATION
FROM
 &DATABASE..ERRORS      A
 INNER JOIN &DATABASE..DETAILS     B
ON A.WEBSITE_ID = B.WEBSITE_ID
  
GROUP BY A.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, A.WEBSITE_ID, A.ERROR_DATE, B.NAME, B.LOCATION

UNION

SELECT
     C.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID          AS WEBSITE_CLASS_ID
    ,C.WEBSITE_ID                AS WEBSITE_ID
    ,DATE(C.SUCCESS_DATE)        AS SUCCESSFUL_CONNECTION
    ,COUNT(C.SUCCESS)            AS COUNT_SUCCESS_CNCTN
    ,B.NAME                      AS WEBSITE_NAME
    ,B.LOCATION                  AS COMPANY_LOCATION
FROM
 &DATABASE..SUCCESS    C
 INNER JOIN
&DATABASE..DETAILS    B
ON C.WEBSITE_ID = B.WEBSITE_ID
GROUP BY C.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID, C.WEBSITE_ID, DATE(C.SUCCESS_DATE), B.NAME, B.LOCATION
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I have to join A.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID to C.WEBSITE_CLASS_ID? Or would it not be necessary since they would have the same class on table B anyway.

Comment: run the code, it will get you exactly your result, the only thing you keep the columns names of the first select

Comment: My only option to run the code would be in the Microsoft Query tool but I have never used it. I am working on running it but one more question please. If I keep the column names of the first select, how would I return both the count of errors and the count of successful connections?

Comment: I am trying to run using the Microsoft Query tool and added the SQL at the bottom of my original question. The Microsoft Query tool does not like the "INNER JOIN" text.

Comment: i need the complete error message, You have to replace the &DATABASE. about that part i am unsure because it is unfamiliar

Comment: I edited the original question to include the code for Microsoft Query tool which has the &DATABASE removed. When I try to run, it first says "SQL Query can't be represented graphically. Continue anyway?" When I click OK, it says "Could not add the table 'INNER'

Comment: you have to check the placement of &databse. you set qa xscx document in it